# SQL - only display echo'd content on first occurance of a new value in a column

Tags: php, mysql

I've got a database that has a column labeled "subcat"

I've got a while loop that loops through rows of database based on "subcat" values.

Inside the while loop, I want to display text only if its the first occurance of any value under subcat.

```
Database Example:

    Subcat    name
    16        gary
    16        betty
    16        harry
    16        jim
    17        george
    17        bill
    18        henry
    18        bob
    18        jonathan
    18        julia
    16        karl
    17        kyle
```

I **ONLY** want "16" to show up once, "17" to show up once, and "18" to show up once and the rest of the values to show up each time.

```
Displayed Example:

**16**
gary
betty
harry
jim
karl

**17**
george
bill

**18**
henry
bob
jonathan
julia
kyle
```

I know how to do the sql statement...I just don't know how to format the while loop to where 16, 17, and 18 only show up on first occurance of the value.  **I don't want predefined values because I want this to scale across any use.**  I set the values elsewhere.  Just the first time any value is seen in a specific column.

**Note**

My code is entirely too long and too big of a database to try to post and explain.  I'm posting a simplified version to find out how to do something that I cannot figure out how to do.  I've got the entire code set up and working EXCEPT the one thing I'm trying to accomplish in this question.  I'm not a new coder trying to get an answer before trying.

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: I have no clue where to start with this.  I've included a database example and how I want it to work.  I've got the entire code set up except the part where it only displays number once.  I'm posting this because I can't figure out how to even begin to do this.  I've searched google for this but cant find ANYTHING.  Whether I'm searching wrong or not, I simply cant find it.

Comment: I would post my code, but my code is extremely complex and has a huge database behind it that would be nearly impossible to explain.  So I'm posting a simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish

Comment: "I want to display text only if its the first occurance of any value under subcat" seems to contradict "I ONLY want "16" to show up once, "17" to show up once, and "18" to show up once ***and the rest of the values to show up each time***"

Comment: I think Mr. Blanchard has offered a clue. And, given that rows in relational database tables have no order, you're going to have to explain what you mean by 'first'.

Comment: you could try a CASE or GROUP BY, *n'est-ca pas?* or an `if(x==y)`. or `COUNT()`.

Comment: @Mawg - Do you see how 16, 17, and 18 are listed multiple times and have multiple names associated with each?  I only want 1 "16" to show up with all the names still looping under, "17" to show up once with all the names looping under, and "18" to show up once with all the names listed under.  The database still loops, but 16, 17, and 18 only show up once

Comment: OK, I get it now. Why not add `ORDER BY subcat` to the end of your `SELECT`?

Comment: I've got that already...but that still won't display a "title" for the FIRST OCCURANCE of a specific subcat ONLY inside the while loop

Comment: I think that it will be a lot easier in PHP. For each row returned, something like `$dispaly[row['subcat]][] = row['name'];`, then afterwards loop through, outputting a header when `the subcat changes. That seems more realistic than a complex SQL Query to get it ordered and with subcat titles.

Comment: One option is to convert your data to a multidimensional array.  http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fb49253e2932a0687d0de948730988085044c140

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set an array before the loop and during the loop check if the key already exists in the array. It depends on how you're retrieving the data but it would be something like this, this assumes the data would be an object:

```
$appeared = array();

while($getdata){
  if(!isset($appeared[$getdata->subcat])){
   echo $getdata->subcat; //first occurs
  }

  ///Your other output

  $appeared[$getdata->subcat] = 1;
}
```